# Difference between git branch --set-upstream-to vs git remote add origin

Tags: git, version-control, versioning

I find it little confusing to know the difference between `git branch --set-upstream-to` vs `git remote add origin` or even `git remote add upstream`

Basically I have a bare repository created with `git init --bare` which is shared on network so that other developers could also push to it so that we have our projects versioned **locally** but not sure which command should I run amongst above three (or if there is some other) to track that central repo eg we push our changes from all projets to that central bare repo and pull/fetch from it too.

Can anyone please enlighten on this?

Comment: Might be of interest (I know it helped me!) [How to move git repository with all branches from bitbucket to github?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906917/how-to-move-git-repository-with-all-branches-from-bitbucket-to-github)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`git remote add` creates a remote, which is a shorthand name for another repository.  `git branch --set-upstream-to` sets a branch to be tracked by the branch in the remote repository specified.

What you are wanting to do is track a remote branch, which is done with `git branch --set-upstream-to` or more simply `git branch -u`.

when you clone a repository from another, a remote is created named `origin` and the branch `master` is checked out.  The command to have your local branch master track the remote branch master is `git branch -u origin/master`, and is executed from the local master branch.

Comment: This is perhaps the most common thing I continue to get confused on with my Git repositories. Thanks for the clarification! I

Comment: what does it mean to tell the remote branch to track another branch?

Comment: Comment space is limited, so short answer is the remote branch does not track another branch -- a local branch tracks a remote branch so it knows if it is up to date or not.  For a more complete answer ask this as a full question.

Answer (score 3):

In order to set the remote tracking branch with `set-upstream-to`, you need to define a remote repo.

When your developers are cloning the bare repo, a remote named `origin` is automatically defined for them.  I.e, on each local clone, a `git remote -v` would list a remote repo named `origin`, referencing the bare repo. They don't need to define a remote named `upstream`.

However, that doesn't mean all the branches from that remote are tracked by a local branch.
That is where `git branch --set-upstream-to` can come into play.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch and http://www.gitguys.com/topics/the-configuration-file-branch-section/ (or http://www.gitguys.com/topics/tracking-branches-and-remote-tracking-branches/) and http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches